# Destroyed /usr/local partition

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I've got three partitions at installation of Ubuntu 12.04, whose mount points are:

```
/  
/usr/local   
/home
```

But I needed a partition so I merged `/usr/local` by copying all its contents into a folder named **local2**. Then I dismounted and formatted partition of `/usr/local`, and then I moved the folder local2 to `/usr/local`.

Ubuntu seems to work fine, but when I turn on PC, Ubuntu start screen says (more or less):

```
/usr/local partition not found. Press S to skip or M to mount it manually.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Edit /etc/fstab (as root) -- remove the line that refers to /usr/local.

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Look for the line that points to `/usr/local`. You probably have that partition set to auto-mount if you specified "defaults" as an option. When partitions are auto-mounted on boot, Ubuntu will check and try to mount it on boot, but since you formatted the said partition, it's UUID have changed and therefore Ubuntu cannot find it on boot.

You just need to edit the `UUID` of the `/usr/local` partition. You can check the `UUID` by running:

```
sudo blkid
```

Once you have the UUID, just copy it and replace the UUID on the line that points to `/usr/local`.

Comment: No, since the user did not move /usr/local to another partition -- the user just moved it to the root partition. There is no need of mounting at all, removing the line from fstab should be fine.

Comment: But the OP said he/she formatted the `/usr/local` partition, by then the UUID would have changed. That's what I think.

Comment: Yes, but it is no longer /usr/local. The system works, local is available, but the stale entry in the fstab causes an error message.